# how to delete /root/.local/lib/python2.7?

Tags: python, pip, uninstallation

I wonder whether /root/.local/lib/python2.7... affect other functions.

Some packages were installed by `sudo pip install --user package` by mistake and it was written in /root/.local/lib/python2.7/...

During uninstallation of some packages by `sudo pip uninstall --user package`, there still is /root/.local/lib/python2.7 directory.
I am afraid, it will continuously make an unexpected problem when updating other packages. So I want to completely remove that directory.

How to remove /root/.local/lib/python2.7 totally?

Will it invoke another problem if I remove /root/.local/lib/python2.7 directly using `rm`?

Comment: What linux distribution do you use?

Comment: It's Debian Jessie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to remove /root/.local/lib/python2.7 totally?

```
sudo rm -rf /root/.local/lib/python2.7
```

> Does it invoke another problems if I remove /root/.local/lib/python2.7 directly by `rm`?

It shouldn't. The directory isn't used for the system python scripts. To
be on the safe side you can rename it and wait a few days before
removing in completely.